# unknown option 2 usage: s_client args

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I want to execute the openssl command in PHP with the shell_exec method.

The command succeeds, but when I run it with shell_exec, I get the following error.

From the error it seems that the option is obsolete, but I can't find an alternative.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
unknown option 2
usage: s_client args
 -host host     - use -connect instead
 -port port     - use -connect instead
 -connect host:port - who to connect to (default is localhost:4433)
 -verify_hostname host - check peer certificate matches "host"
 -verify_email email - check peer certificate matches "email"
 -verify_ip ipaddr - check peer certificate matches "ipaddr"
 -verify arg   - turn on peer certificate verification
 -verify_return_error - return verification errors
 -cert arg     - certificate file to use, PEM format assumed
 -certform arg - certificate format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -key arg      - Private key file to use, in cert file if
                 not specified but cert file is.
 -keyform arg  - key format (PEM or DER) PEM default
 -pass arg     - private key file pass phrase source
 -CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's
 -CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's
 -trusted_first - Use trusted CA's first when building the trust chain
```

```
# OpenSSL Version
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

$response = shell_exec('openssl s_client -servername {$domain_name} -connect {$domain_name}:443 2 >/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | grep notAfter | sed -e s#notAfter=##');
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `2 >/dev/null` is to redirect errors to null, you should delete the space `2>/dev/null`, else the 2 will be considered as an command argument

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

As for `2 >/dev/null`, my intention is to limit the following output to `Mar 5 12:59:52 2022 GMT

```
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = music-deluxe.net
verify return:1
Mar 5 12:59:52 2022 GMT
````